# Healthkit privacy policy, how?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, healthkit, privacy-policy

When trying to submit a new release with access to HealthKit information I get an error telling me to provide a privacy statement for all the languages in which the app is localised. Where do I find these statements? 
I would not really know what to write in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any rate:
https://www.iubenda.com
produces a reasonable policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is Private Policy for my app which uses HealthKit: https://medium.com/@kirillchekanov/information-gathering-and-usage-80add2213132#.8yep3u8dz. It is fine for Apple Review team.

You should also write that your app uses HealthKit in app's description in ItunesConnect (e.g  'HealthKit displays the amount of steps you need to make today').

Comment: This information seems to focus on web usage, not health-kit. Perhaps you typed the wrong link.

Comment: @Fabrizio Bartolomucci Yes, but as I told this PP is fine to Apple Review team. As for HealthKit - just write about it in your description and app will be approved.

Comment: I would not know what to take out of your notice, you talk about cookies and all things regarding web usage... for that matter I have a similar statement for another app to yours. Can you point me to some proper health-kit statement?

Comment: If that is fine, I could even enter the first page of Romeo and Juliet...